# C++ freeing memory allocation of array with sub arrays

Tags: c++

Theoretically, is it enough if I only delete `arrays` and `results` but don't delete `sub_array` inside of `arrays` in the following code snippet, before `return 0;` or do I have to first delete all the `sub_array` before I can safely delete `arrays` and `results`.

```
int main() {

    int subarrays, queries;

    cin >> subarrays >> queries;

    int** arrays = new int* [subarrays]();

    int* results = new int[queries];

    for (int i = 0; i < subarrays; i++) {

        int length;
        cin >> length;

        int* sub_array = new int[length];

        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {

            int element;
            cin >> element;

            sub_array[j] = element;
        }

        arrays[i] = sub_array;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) {

        int query_from, arr_index;
        cin >> query_from >> arr_index;

        results[i] = arrays[query_from][arr_index];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) {

        cout << results[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) { delete[] arrays[i]; } delete[] arrays; delete[] results;`

Comment: An array of arrays is very rarely what you want (despite the fact that every C++ beginner learns first about `char** argv`). If, for example, you need a data structure with variable-length elements that can be removed, you might want a linked list if they’ll be accessed in order, or a hash table if you need constant-time random access. (Although you could implement a kind of unordered map this way, if the map is very dense.) You might also be able to use a “rectangular” array of fixed dimension. If you need a sparse matrix, compressed sparse row is more efficient.

Comment: If you do need this particular data structure, it should be a `std::vector<std::string>` or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't delete `sub_array` because the buffer it points to is stored in `arrays[n]`. As the only way you could delete `sub_array` is inside the block scope it was declared (which is the for loop), if you do delete it then `arrays[n]` will be a `dangling pointer` (a pointer that points to a freed or invalid memory block) and dangling pointers are **evil**.

What you should do about `arrays` and `sub_array` is when they are not needed anymore, you first iterate through all elements of `arrays`, deleting each one of them and after this, delete `arrays` itself. Something like:

```
// when you are done with them
for(auto i = 0; i < subarrays; i++)
{
    delete[] arrays[i];
}

delete[] arrays;
```

As a side-note you should consider using [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) in this code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OP saves that pointer at `arrays[i] = sub_array;`. Therefore deleting `arrays[n]` will free the memory allocated by `int* sub_array = new int[length];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to first delete all the sub_array before I can safely delete arrays and results to prevent memory leak.

You can employ a loop to go through the sub-arrays in the array.